# Blank White Screen at localhost:8080 with Tomcat 8 on OSX 10.8.5

Tags: macos, rest, tomcat, servlets, tomcat8

I followed this tutorial exactly: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/rest/jersey/jersey-hello-world-example/

But I just see a blank white screen when I go to: `http://localhost:8080/JAXRS-HelloWorld/rest/helloWorldREST/JavaCodeGeeks?value=enjoy-REST`

I started tomcat by running the command `catalina run`

Should I be doing something differently to deploy the webapp?

Comment: Can you specify how to deploy your application to Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

I have just tested the sample application on Tomcat 8 and it works without any issue.
As expected it prints out the below message in the browser when called.

"Hello from: JavaCodeGeeks : enjoy-REST"

There are couple of things that I can think of might causing the problems in your case.

1. You are missing any of the steps specified in the tutorial.
2. You are not deploying the "JAXRS-HelloWorld.war" into Tomcat properly.
3. I hope have setup your CATALINA_HOME properly in order to call the "catalina run" in commadline.

To resolve your problems.

1. Instead of following the steps in the tutorial, download the attached project and generate the war file as specified and deploy it and see if it works.
2. To deploy the project in tomcat, you have to copy the "JAXRS-HelloWorld.war" file into $CATALINA_BASE/webapps folder and then start the server.
3. There are couple of ways to start the Tomcat server. One that you have chosen is the commandlne. To start the Tomcat server from caommandline either you have to change directory(cd $CATALINA_BASE/bin) to Tomcat home bin folder and the call catalina.bat/catalina.sh with run or start command Or set the CATALINA_HOME enviorenment variable and then call the same command from anywhere in your commandline.

Note:
Also check the Tomcat logs for specific issues or errors.